# How to run `nvm` for Windows through SSH?

Tags: windows, command-line, ssh, openssh, nvm

I'm on macOS and try to run `nvm` on a Windows host via OpenSSH. I installed `nvm` via `scoop install nvm` on my Windows remote. The environment variables are set and `where nvm` resolves properly, but trying to access `nvm` through `ssh` gets me stuck, so that I can only cancel (nothing happens):

```sh
> ssh windev where nvm
C:\Users\mbx\scoop\apps\nvm\current\nvm.exe
> ssh windev nvm -v
^C
> ssh windev cmd /c nvm -v
^C
> ssh windev "cmd /c nvm"
^C
```

When I connect via `ssh windev` and run `nvm -v`, it works. My current guess is that Windows user environment variables are not set when I attempt to run a remote commend instantly, as the sign in to the user only happens afterwards? It should give an error, but it acts like my destination is invalid, but that doesn't explain things like `ssh windev echo test` work as expected.

I noticed that I had to register my public key in `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys` as well, to make my alias destination work without password prompt. So this might be related, but is generally necessary on Windows to make password-less prompts work, as my user is part of the Administrator group.

`ssh windev echo %PATH%` also prints:

> `C:\ProgramData\scoop\shims;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\mbx\scoop\apps\python\current\Scripts;C:\Users\mbx\scoop\apps\python\current;C:\Users\mbx\scoop\apps\nvm\current;C:\Users\mbx\scoop\apps\nvm\current\nodejs\nodejs;C:\Users\mbx\scoop\shims;C:\Users\mbx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\mbx\.dotnet\tools;C:\git-sdk-64\mingw64\bin;C:\git-sdk-64\mingw32\bin;`

LGTM, so what is going on, how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have no full explanation other than `nvm` is indeed found via `ssh windev nvm -v`, but it is stuck, because anything is missing that is setup only an interactive shell. Contrary to the unix NVM, NVM for Windows doesn't require any manual environment setup, but something is missing in the login shell that `nvm` needs anyways.

The solution is to simply force an interactive shell via `ssh -t windev nvm -v`. This works and returns the version as expected. Beware that this will cause the "Connection to XX.XX.XX.XX closed." literal to be outputted at the end of the execution. It basically simulates a manual login, pasting of the command and exiting.